# discord.py Dictionary of all roles

Tags: python, dictionary, discord, discord.py

I'd like to create a dictionary with all roles of a guild for easier use in development:
`roles_dictionary = {'role1': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='role1') }` etc.

I'd like to always be able to access any role using:
`roles_dictionary['role1']`

I already tried putting it into the on_ready() function, however it seems as if you shouldn't do stuff like that in the on_ready() function, since whenever I tried closing the program it just restarted the bot in two instances. (Not sure why that happened, however my theory is, that I can't do anything until the on_ready() function is done, meaning I made API calls before the bot was ready)

This is the code I have atm:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            print(
                f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
                f'{guild.name} (id: {guild.id})'
            )
            break
```

```
guild = client.get_guild(1099387953337335909)
                roles_dict = {'owner_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Paradise Founder'),
                              'admin_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='️ Island Manager'),
                              'moderator_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Palm Guardian'),
                              'known_member_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Tiki VIP'),
                              'booster_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Starfish Supporter'),
                              'bot_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Coconut Companion'),
                              'member_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Beachcomber'),
                              'new_member_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Seashell Seeker'),
                              'muted_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Silent Sunset')}
```

I can't use any other functions in the on_ready() function and I tried creating the dictionary in the on_ready() function, however I couldn't access it and whenever I tried making the dictionary global, the weird startup issue started occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with doing this kind of thing in the `on_ready`, what I am assuming is happening is that the dict you are creating is being garbage-collected as it is only available within that scope.

The easiest way to do this (imo) would be to subclass the standard bot class and make this new dict a member of it.

```py
class MyBot(discord.Bot): # subclass discord.Bot
    async def on_ready(self): # override the on_ready event
        for guild in self.guilds:
            if guild.name == GUILD:
                self.roleDict = {'owner_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Paradise Founder'),
                              'admin_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='️ Island Manager'),
                              'moderator_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Palm Guardian'),
                              'known_member_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Tiki VIP'),
                              'booster_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Starfish Supporter'),
                              'bot_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Coconut Companion'),
                              'member_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Beachcomber'),
                              'new_member_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Seashell Seeker'),
                              'muted_role': discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=' Silent Sunset')}

bot = MyBot() # create an instance of MyBot
bot.run("TOKEN") # run the bot
```

Then, to access this new dict, you would do as such:
`bot.roleDict['moderator_role']`

It's important to note that because you are creating this in the `on_ready`, if a role is created or removed, the roleDict will not reflect this data. I would rebuild it if this occurs.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach! I figured out the problem:
I used from main import roles_dict in another .py file and for some reason that was the problem. Do you have any idea as to why?

Comment: @Dan Honestly no, but using globals in this way in Python is generally frowned upon so I would not be surprised if they're causing some kind of import-chain chaos or something

Comment: I implemented your very nice way, but whenever I, for example try to import the client to another .py file, it still causes the error. I don't understand as to why. I found out that there is something called extensions, but I don't think that applies to my case

Comment: @Dan, could you be more specific? What error?